# How to check if regular expression matches the whole string?

Tags: regex, perl

I've got a regex that matches stuff like this:
asdasd[text];
it works fine one step at a time, but if a have something like:

```
$badinput="add[2,5,525];print['peron'];print['asd','cgfg];time;print['iudofiusdoif'];"; #time should not be matched
```

this is the code for now:

```
verify($badinput);
sub verify
{
#returns 1 if it's ok, or the text that breaks the match
    my $inp = pop;
    if ($inp =~ /^(?:\w{2,6}\[(?<!\\\[).*?\](?<!\\\]);)+$/s)
    {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0; #should be the text that breaks the match or the char number
    };
}
```

It returns 1 no matter what if the first instruction matches. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sub verify
{
  return ($_[0] =~ m/^((?:\w{2,6}\[[^\]]*\];)+)$/)? 1 : 0;
}
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/WGI1Y).

Answer (score 2):

One way. My regular expression it's similar to yours but without look-behind.

An example. Content of `script.pl`:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <DATA> ) {
        chomp;
        printf qq|%s ==> %s\n|, $_, ( m/^(\w{2,6}\[[^]]*\];)+$/ ) ? q|ok| : q|not ok|;
}

__DATA__
add[2,5,525];print['peron'];print['asd','cgfg];time;print['iudofiusdoif'];
add[2,5,525];print['peron'];print['asd','cgfg];print['iudofiusdoif'];
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

With following output:

```
add[2,5,525];print['peron'];print['asd','cgfg];time;print['iudofiusdoif']; ==> not ok
add[2,5,525];print['peron'];print['asd','cgfg];print['iudofiusdoif']; ==> ok
```